# WCF unable to locate ConnectionString

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, entity-framework, wcf

Over the last couple of days I've been researching WCF. I've been reading various discussions and following a number of different walkthroughs, most notably the one linked below.

[WCF Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I'm now trying to convert these skills into a different scenario. The file structure is exactly the same as what was stated in the aforementioned walkthrough. There is one WCF Service Library, a Host (Console Application) and a Client (Console Application). The host is setup in the same manor as the walkthrough, the client has been altered to allow user input instead of hardcoded values and the WCF code has been provided below.

After a value is provided the WCF Library will run until the following line `var userData = repository.GetById(userId);`. When the breakpoint is reached and I step over, an exception is thrown stating that the ConnectionString expected doesn't exist. I've tested putting the connection string in the Client and WCF projects but to no avail. I've also ensured EntityFramework and Service.Configuration DLLs are also added as references.

It's possible I am missing another DLL, App.config setting or I've completely messed up and misinterpretted what I can do with a WCF Service Library so I'm looking for some advice on how to rectify the issue in the previous paragraph or a link which helps me understand the problem

IService.cs Code

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "....")]
public interface IUser
{
    [OperationContract]
    User GetUser(int userId = 0);
}

[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Service.cs Code

```
public class UserService : IUser
{
    public User GetUser(int userId = 0)
    {
        User user = null;

        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var repository = new Repository(context);
            var userData = repository.GetById(userId);

            if (userData != null)
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    FirstName = userData.CustomerFirstName,
                    LastName = userData.CustomerSurname,
                    UserName = userData.CustomerEmail
                };

                Console.WriteLine("UserId : {0}", userId);
                Console.WriteLine("FirstName : {0}", userData.CustomerFirstName);
                Console.WriteLine("LastName : {0}", userData.CustomerSurname);
                Console.WriteLine("UserName : {0}", userData.CustomerEmail);
            }
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
<add name="CONTEXT"
     connectionString="Server=SERVER;Database=DATABASE;uid=DATABASE;pwd=DATABASE;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Can we see your connection string?

Comment: Edited the question, the connection string was modified accordingly.

Comment: Is this located on the server directly, if so: `Server=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI; Database=master` or `Data Source=.; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=DbName`.  My theory is that it is having trouble trying to determine the `connectionString` location.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The 3 projects all have a reference to the Connection String I've posted, to rule out any problem. When I try and do something similar to 'ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;' no data is located and it returns null so it seems your theory is correct. This is why I am assuming there is a missing configuration setting in the APP.CONFIG file/s or a DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string must be set in the App.config of the executing assembly, not in the assembly directly using it. This means that although your service implementation (`Service.cs`) is located in your WCF Library assembly, the connection string must be located in the App.config of your host project. If you declare an App.config file into your WCF Library, it will simply be ignored.

The client will not access the database, it will consume your service which is who accesses the database. Therefore, there is no need to declare the connectiong string in the client App.config.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't quite understand why but it has started working. After looking at this for a number of hours yesterday I decided to leave it and come back with a fresh mind. I read yesterday the connection string needed to be in the HOST file but during testing  it wasn't picking up the connectionString. Since doing another process of elimination this morning it has started to work and the problem has been rectified. As you're correct in your response I'll mark it as correct.